# Tkinter widget where User chooses parameter values, but how do I store these values?

Tags: python, tkinter

My objective is to create three variables called 'Number of pipes','Anisotropy ratio', 'Filter depth (in cm)' which values are chosen by the user (through a User interface). I achieved to create the scrollbar of Tkinter and to enter values but these are not stored as variables. Could someone give me a hand solving that? I am new in Python and specially I am struggling with Tkinter. The code is developped in Python 3.7:

```
root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry('1000x1000') 



#Description show in window
info=tk.Label(root,anchor='e')
info.pack()

#Parameters


parameters = ('Number of pipes','Anisotropy ratio', 'Filter depth (in cm)')

def ask_parameter(entry):

    user_pipes = str (entry['Number of pipes'].get()) 


    user_aniso = str (entry['Anisotropy ratio'].get()) #effective screen length = b

    user_depth = str (entry['Filter depth (in cm)'].get()) 
    print(user_pipes,user_aniso,user_depth)


#if parameters 
#        return True
#    else:
#        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning ('Only numbers', 'Try again')
#        return True
#        


def form(parameters):
    entry = {}
    for parameter in parameters:
        print(parameter)
        row = tk.Frame(root)
        lab = tk.Label(row, width=15, text=parameter+": ", anchor='w')
        ent = tk.Entry(row)      
        row.pack(side=tk.TOP, 
                 fill=tk.X, 
                 padx=2, 
                 pady=2)
        lab.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        ent.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.YES,fill=tk.X)
        entry[parameter] = ent
    return entry


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ents = form(parameters)


save_button = tk.Button(root)
save_button.configure(text='Save', command=lambda: ask_parameter(ents))
save_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Any problem is shown with the code but the parameters are not stored as variables with the entered values.
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I don't understand what the scrollbar has to do with this. Why do you need a scrollbar for three entries?

Comment: You are right, There is no need. I deleted from the code.

Comment: But still my problem is that I don't achieve to create this entered values in the variables...

Comment: you might want to remove the mention of scrollbar in the title too, since this question has nothing to do with scrollbars.

Comment: What do you mean the parameters are not stored as variables? When I add a print statement to your `ask_parameters()` function to print all 3 variables I get the values I put into the entry fields printed to screen as expected. What exactly is the problem? That said you do not need to use `str()` on `get()`. As `get()` always returns a string value from entry fields.

Comment: Indeed, sorry I was trying to find the values in the variable console and they were not appearing. Once I print the variabes the values appeared.Sorry for the misunderstanding and thank you for your help.

Comment: @nuria_mc no worries. `print()` is your friend when it comes to working things out. My most used trouble shooting tool :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is storing the values inputted through the GUI to variables, your problem is probably that your variables aren't global, so you won't be able to use them outside of the function they are created in. you can either get around this with a `return`, or make them global by putting `global varname` above the definition of each variable as well as at the start of every function that will use it.